# Can I install Lutron Caseta dimmer switches with this set up?

Tags: electrical, smart-switch

I have three zones of lighting for my kitchen and three toggle switches (i.e., all single poles). I took the plate off the wall and was a bit confused. I diagrammed the wire arrangement in MS paint (please excuse my artistic ability). The third switch not having a ground was confusing to me, but not that big of a deal since I think I can make do with it. I am confused about the fact that there are only two pairs of wires between the three switches. I do have an electrician, but he'd charge me to come take a look even if it's not possible. Plus there's a minimum and this is a very small job. Can someone explain what I'm looking at?

[image]

Here's what I'm thinking of doing (this time just not including the neutrals and ground wires for clarity):

[image]

Comment: Is rerunning the cabling from the switch box back to the light an option?

Comment: Are the neutrals connected to each other, or are they capped off independently?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Capped off independently

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Not really feasible right now, unfortunately

Comment: Why aren't you just using pico remotes? This should certainly be possible to wire. Do you have a tester and are you able to label line and load in your drawing? Are there other switches which also toggle the lights (3-way switches?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Here's what it looks like to me:

1. The black from the left cable is the line hot and it goes to one contact of each on the three switches (bottom contact in your diagram).
2. The reds are the switched hots of the left and center switches. The other black (right cable) is the switched hot for the right switch.

I think this is a defective arrangement because the net current in each cable is not balanced. Repurposing the currently unused white wires might possibly allow this to be remedied, but I can't see how.

Comment: I have a 3-gang box with three switches for two different lights and one receptacle that are wired with a single line hot like this. I last had the switch plate off 40 years ago but I think there is a separate /2 cable to each of the three outlets. If so, that would be four /2 cables in the box. Each of the three cables to the outlets would have a neutral and a switched hot. The fourth cable would be line hot and (line) neutral.  In this arrangement the currents are balanced in each cable. Current in one wire equals current in the other.

Comment: I'm going to send this image to my electrician and hope he can let me know of a way to do it without him waiting. I've popped a few switches off now and this is the way the previous owner must have done all the switches. I'll have to figure out if it's okay.

Comment: How are the neutrals getting to each light fixture? There must be cables going from one light box to another. If so, this is highly irregular. You would need to understand the wires and connections in each light box.

Comment: It could be the right hand cable goes to the same box as the left hand. Then there are cables from there carrying neutral and  switched hot to the other two lights.

Comment: Do you have a VOM and a non-contact voltage tester? With the breaker on first check withb the non-contact tester that neither white is hot. Then turn the breaker off and with the VOM measure the resistance between the two whites. If it is close to zero, they are connected and are probably good neutrals. To confirm this plug a long enough extension cord into a receptacle on another circuit. Measure the resistance between the whites and the neutral  of the extension cord. If this is low, then the two whites are neutrals.

Comment: Did exactly this and they are indeed good neutrals. Wired up the Caseta dimmers following the instructions on their website and everything is working almost perfectly. The dimming is a little wonky where one zone is not dimming unless another is dimmed. Going to look into that.

Comment: Do the Caseta dimmers require a neutral to be connected to them?

Comment: No, they work without the neutral. They get a load wire and a hot wire (doesn't matter which side) and obviously a ground. I pigtailed the hot wire for the three dimmers and used the load that the previous toggles were using. It seems to be working correctly (except that the dimmers are wonky).

Comment: Looks like you would have to pull out the fixtures and look into the boxes to determine how this connected.